# Taylor series of functions with matrix input

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, taylor-expansion, lie-groups

Today my professor said something interesting, replace $x$ in $f(x)$ with matrix  \begin{bmatrix}x&1\\0&x\end{bmatrix}

Then $$f(\begin{bmatrix}x&1\\0&x\end{bmatrix}) = f(x)\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} + f^{'}(x)\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

and asked us to find the higher order terms ($f^{''}(x), f^{'''}(x) ....$)  and extend it to multi variable functions.

I didn't understand how he came up with this.

After some googling, this seems similar to matrix exponential from lie groups.

Comment: It sure looks interesting but you have some typos.

Comment: I'm writing this out of memory, I didn't note it down. Had to run to another class.

Comment: There’s a difference between that being the exact expansion and those being the first two terms of an infinite expansion. Do you know which one it is? I’m just as interested in finding the solution as you, so please don’t think I’m being condescendingly pedantic.

Comment: First two terms of an infinite expansion. He was talking about taylor series and linear approximations before mentioning this.

Comment: Wait, if $x=\begin{bmatrix}x&1\\0&x\end{bmatrix}$ then $x$ is just an infinitely-large matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that, as mentioned by mathreadler in his comment on the question itself, that there is indeed a typo and that the correct formula may be written

$f \left (\begin{bmatrix} x & 1 \\ 0 & x \end{bmatrix} \right ) = f(x)I + f'(x)N, \tag 0$

with $I$ and $N$ explained in what follows.

I assume $f(x)$ is represented by a Taylor series about $x = 0$:

$f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \dfrac{1}{2}f''(0)x^2 + \ldots = \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{n!} f^{(n)}(0) x^n; \tag 1$

we have

$\begin{bmatrix} x & 1 \\ 0 & x \end{bmatrix}^n = \left ( \begin{bmatrix} x & 0 \\ 0 & x \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \right )^n = \left ( x\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \right )^n; \tag 2$

setting

$I = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \tag 3$

and

$N =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \; N^2 = 0, \tag 4$

we write

$\begin{bmatrix} x & 1 \\ 0 & x \end{bmatrix}^n = (xI + N)^n; \tag 5$

since $IN = NI$, (5) may be subject to the ordinary binomial expansion, and since $N^2 = 0$, the terms containing the powers of $N$ greater than the second vanish; thus

$\begin{bmatrix} x & 1 \\ 0 & x \end{bmatrix}^n = (xI + N)^n = x^nI + nx^{n - 1}N; \tag 6$

if we substitute this into (1) we obtain

$f \left (\begin{bmatrix} x & 1 \\ 0 & x \end{bmatrix} \right ) = f(0)I + f'(0)(xI + N) + \dfrac{1}{2}f''(0) (x^2 I + 2xN) + \ldots$
$= (f(0) + f'(0)x + \dfrac{1}{2} f''(0)x^2 + \ldots)I + (f'(0) + f''(0)x + \ldots)N$
$= \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{n!} f^{(n)}(0)(xI + N)^n = \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(0)(x^nI + nx^{n - 1}N)$
$= \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{n!} f^{(n)}(0)x^nI + \sum_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{n!} f^{(n)}(0)nx^{n - 1}N$
$= \left ( \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{n!} f^{(n)}(0)x^n \right ) I + \left ( \displaystyle \sum_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{(n - 1)!} f^{(n)}(0)x^{n - 1} \right )N; \tag7$

we observe that the coefficient of $I$ is the Taylor series of $f(x)$ and that of $N$ is the Talylor series of $f'(x)$; thus

$f \left (\begin{bmatrix} x & 1 \\ 0 & x \end{bmatrix} \right ) = f(x)I + f'(x)N. \tag 8$

This "expansion" is in fact exact on any inteval containing $0$ on which the Taylor series for $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ converge.

Answer (score 3):

Let's first try to understand what happens in the case of polynomials: Take some polynomial function $f: \mathbb{R\to \mathbb{R}}$. We would like to define $f(X)$, where $X$ is a real $n\times n$ matrix for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $f$ is a polynomial, we have $$f(x)=p_0x^0+p_1x+p_2x^2+...+p_mx^m$$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $(p_k)_{k=0}^m \in \mathbb{R^m}$. Since $n \times n$ matrices, like real numbers, can be added and multiplied by itself, it is only natural to define
$$f(X)=p_0X^0+p_1X^1+p_2X^2+...+p_mX^m,$$
where $X^0$ is the identity matrix. So for any *polynomial* function $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ we can define a corresponding matrix function $F: \mathbb{R^{n\times n}} \to \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$.

But we want more: We want to define $f(X)$ for some larger class of functions where $f$ isn't necessarily a polynomial anymore. Let's consider *power series*, which in some sense are just "infinite polynomials". Take a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which can be written as $$f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty q_jx^j$$
for some $(q_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, where the series of course has to converge for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then analogous to the polynomial case we would like to define for an $n\times n$ matrix $X$ $$f(X):=\sum_{j=0}^\infty q_jX^j.$$ But we have to make sure that this series converges for all $X\in\mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$ as well, otherwise this expression doesn't make any sense! Now technically we need a norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ to talk about convergence, but the choice doesn't really matter because all norms on finite dimensional vector spaces are equivalent. Let's take the norm $\|X\|:=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j=0}^n |X_{i,j}|^2}$ because it has the convenient property of being submultiplicative, that is $\|XY\|\leq\|X\|\|Y\|$ for all $X,Y \in \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$, and that will be useful in the following argument:

$$\|\sum_{j=0}^{m+n}q_jX^j-\sum_{j=0}^{m}q_jX^j\|=\|\sum_{j=m+1}^{m+n}q_jX^j\|\leq \sum_{j=m+1}^{m+n}|q_j\\|X^j\| \leq \sum_{j=m+1}^{m+n}|q_j\\|X\|^j \rightarrow 0,$$ for $n\to \infty$ and any $m\in\mathbb{N}$ since the power series $\sum_{j=0}^\infty q_jx^j$ was assumed to have a radius of convergence of infinity, so it converges absolutely everywhere. Because we've shown that $(\sum_{j=0}^n q_jX^j)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in the complete space $(\mathbb{R^{n \times n}}, \|\cdot\|)$, the series converges everywhere (even absolutely).

So now we can define $f(X)$ for any *power series* function $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.  In particular, if $f$ is an infinitely differentiable function for which it's Taylor series converges in $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ to $f$,  we have defined $f(X)$ (after shifting $x \mapsto (x-x_0)$), and it is given by
$$f(X)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(j)}(x_0)}{j!}(X-x_0I)^j.$$ By setting $f=\exp$, you get the matrix exponential of which you talked about in your question.

Now finally if $X=\begin{bmatrix}x&1\\0&x\end{bmatrix}$, then after multiplying some matrices one gets for $x\neq x_0$
$$f(X)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}\begin{bmatrix}(x-x_0)^n&\frac{n}{(x-x_0)^{n-1}}\\0&(x-x_0)^n\end{bmatrix}.$$ For $x=x_0$, it just reduces to the polynomial case $$f(X)=f(x)\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}+f'(x)\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$
I think you have an error in your question because for any $x_0$ this doesn't line up with the expression you gave.

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor Series can be expressed as:

$$ f(x + h) = f(x) + hf'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x) + \frac{h^3}{3!} f'''(x) + \dots $$

Letting $x = xI_2$ and $ h = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

We see that $h^n = 0_{2\times2}$ for $n \geq 2$.

Yielding $$ f(x + h) = f(x) + hf'(x) $$

This is the motivation for Dual Numbers and automatic differentiation.